# How to access ASP.NET localhost from web?

Tags: asp.net, localhost

My Visual Studio project URL is http://localhost:58167/. But if I try to run `<my_ip>:58167` - I got nothing. I am definitely not a web guy. Can someone of you help me?

P.S. I take my ip from `ipconfig`.

Comment: how to ask is your first step: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask show us what you've tried then we can help you. Your question is really unclear.

Comment: Web or from another computer in the same network???

Comment: @ChathurangaRanasinghe web would be the best one, but at least same network.

Comment: Try this  [link](http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer)